# Hiking trails on Bainbridge Island to see the skyline of Seattle?

Tags: hiking, recommendations, seattle

Bainbridge Island is a relatively small island that can be reached from downtown Seattle by ferry in about 30 minutes. I read that there are a lot of hiking trails on the island, and I even found a list of trails: http://www.biparks.org/biparks_site/trails/trail-finder.htm

The question now is: Does any of these marked trails provide a good view on the skyline of Seattle? I'm especially interested in slightly challenging trails, i.e. trails with at least 5 miles.

Comment: Your best bet for views of the Seattle skyline is probably from the ferry to/from the island.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a great view trail at the superfund site (Pritchard Park) and Rockaway Beach but really most of the trails do not give a view of Seattle.